# NoClassDefFoundError using jcifs library

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, ear, pom.xml, jcifs

I have a Maven project (ejb container) where I need to use the jcifs library.
I made the entries in pom.xml like:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
     <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.17</version>
     <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Everything is okay, I see the jar file inside the ear package, I see it also in the dependencies of the project, I can use the classes but at runtime I get:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/smb/SmbFile
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:63)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have put the jar file inside the libs folder of the JBoss server and it works now. But why it doesn't see the jar from the package ?

Comment: Ok, I have another dependency in the pom, but as same I get NoClassDefFoundError at runtime. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the webproject and go to properties -> Java EE Module Dependencies. Check the Maven dependencies is checked.If not check and redeploy .

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help the people who are as stupid as I am. This is not really the about the same scenario as asked for in this question, but this question helped me to figure out my problem.

I wrote a little code in a scratch file, in my case in Intellij. Before that I added the jcifs dependency to my maven project, assuming that the scratch file would find it there, which in hindsight is a bit stupid, because how would the scratch space know.

So my hint is to have a look where the dependency will actually have an effect, i.e. is available - compile time, runtime, scratch space?

Also I wanted to mention that I used this library, which works very fine for me https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj.

So in my case I edited the run configuration so that it would take the maven modules configuration into the classpath.

So my guess is that @SANN3 's answer is correct for the actual question.

[image]